# Conditions on coefficients of complex power series to ensure it is real

Tags: complex-analysis, power-series

Given a complex valued function $f(z)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} a_nz^n$ with radius of convergence $R>0$, and $\rho\in (0,R)$, is there an if and only if giving that $f([0,\rho])\subset \mathbb{R}$?

So obviously if $a_n\in \mathbb{R}$ for all $n$, then the result holds, and we clearly need that $a_0\in \mathbb{R}$. So since $\rho<R$, the power series converges uniformly and absolutely on $[0,\rho]$ so we can do rearrangements and such. One idea is that if this is true, and $r\in [0,\rho]$, then $\sum a_n r^n -\overline{\sum a_n r^n}=0=\sum (a_n-\overline{a_n})r^n$. If we divide everything by $2i$, we can get that each term is a real number, but not necessarily positive. Since it converges absolutely, $\sum |a_n|r^n=\sum |\overline{a_n}|r^n$, so subtracting gives $\sum |a_n|-|\overline{a_n}| r^n=0\leq \sum |a_n -\overline{a_n}|r^n$, but this doesn't seem to go anywhere. We also know that $f([0,\rho])$ is compact, but this doesn't appear to be helpful.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, $f([0,\rho])\subset \mathbb R$ if and only if all $a_n$ are real.

Define $$g(z)=\overline{f(\overline{z})} = \sum_{i=0}^\infty \overline{a_i}z^i$$

Then $f(z)-g(z)=0$ for $z\in[0,\rho]$. But $f(z)-g(z)=\sum (a_i-\overline{a_i})z^i$. So $a_i=\overline{a_i}$.

(You need to know that a non-zero analytic function can have at most countably many zeros.)

Comment: We haven't shown this yet, but I think I can prove it. Thank you!